# 時間帯毎のユニークなユーザーと合計注文数を確認したい

Tags: sql

以下のようなテーブルがあった際に、月単位（下記の例なら2021年1月）において、時間帯毎のユニークなcustomer_idのカウント、注文数を出すにはどのようなクエリで実現可能でしょうか。

table:

```
order_timestamp, customer_id, order_id
2021-01-01 23:31:31,aaa,111
2021-01-02 01:22:11,bbb,123
2021-01-31 07:20:55,aaa,444
```

customer_idは同じcustomer毎に振られたユニークなID、order_idは注文毎のユニークなIDとなります。

例えばAというユーザーが、2021年1月に朝の8時に3回購入していた場合、
8時のorder_countsとしては「3」となりますが、unique_customer_countsとしては「1」となります。

期待する結果としては、時間帯毎にどれくらいの頻度で購入されているかがわかるデータとなり、どの時間帯にリピーターが多いかを探りたいと考えています。

以下のようなクエリを実行すれば実現できるのではと思い試しましたが、なぜかorder_countsとunique_customer_countsが同じ数字になってしまいます。

もしこの結果が正しいのであれば、各customerがその時間帯には1ヶ月に1回しか購入していないことになり、不自然な結果となってしまいます。

```
SELECT
date_trunc('hour', order_timestamp) as　hour
COUNT(order_id) as order_counts
COUNT(distinct customer_id) as unique_customer_counts

FROM table

WHERE 1=1 
AND MONTH(order_timestamp) = 1
AND YEAR(order_timestamp) = 2021

GROUP BY 1
```

念の為Selectのdate_truncの部分を抜いてみると、order_countsとunique_customer_countsに明確な差が出ますので、データ自体が間違っているということはないようです。

```
SELECT
COUNT(order_id) as order_counts
COUNT(distinct customer_id) as unique_customer_counts

FROM table

WHERE 1=1 
AND MONTH(order_timestamp) = 1
AND YEAR(order_timestamp) = 2021
```

Comment: 使用されている RDBMS は、 Microsoft SQL Server でしょうか？ 標準SQL 以外の関数を利用されるなら、質問時に利用している RDBMS を明示した方が良いです。

Comment: 失礼しました。よくわかっておらず申し訳ないのですが、prestoを利用しております。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

時間帯でグループ化すれば良いのではないでしょうか。
以下、`MySQL 8.0` での実行結果です。

**table schema**

```sql
CREATE TABLE tbl (
  order_timestamp datetime,
  customer_id varchar(3),
  order_id int
);
```

**test records**

```sql
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
('2021-01-01 08:50:00', 'A', 111),
('2021-01-02 01:22:11', 'B', 123),
('2021-01-10 08:30:00', 'A', 222),
('2021-01-25 08:10:00', 'A', 333),
('2021-01-31 23:20:55', 'C', 444)
```

**sql query statement**

```sql
SELECT
  HOUR(order_timestamp) AS hour,
  COUNT(order_id) AS order_counts,
  COUNT(distinct customer_id) AS unique_customer_counts
FROM tbl
WHERE 1=1 
  AND MONTH(order_timestamp) = 1
  AND YEAR(order_timestamp) = 2021
GROUP BY hour ORDER BY hour
```

**query result**

| hour | order_counts | unique_customer_counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 8 | 3 | 1 |
| 23 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: ありがとうございます！うまくいきました。